# Cell Editing on checkchange event of a checkcolumn

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have been looking for a solution to this in sencha forum as well as on stack overflow. I was unable to get a proper solution to this issue.  I want to edit a particular cell of a row in a grid on checkchange event of a check column in that row.

Following is the code-

```
         var unitStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                            fields: ['phone'], 
                            autoLoad:true ,
                             proxy: {
    type: 'memory',

}
                        });

         var abc=Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
storeId:'simpsonsStore',
fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
data:{'items':[
    { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
    { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
    { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
    { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
]},
proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'items'
    }
}
   });
   var cellEditing=Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
      clicksToEdit: 1,
   });
      Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
title: 'Simpsons',
 plugins: [cellEditing],
store: abc,
columns: [
{xtype:'checkcolumn' ,id:'check',dataIndex:'check', text:'Select' ,listeners:{
        checkchange:function( checkbox, rowIndex, checked, eOpts ){
                 if(checked==true){
                    //var abc=checkbox.up('grid').getStore().getAt(rowIndex).get('name');
                  var x=[{'phone':'2'},{'phone':'3'}];
                  unitStore.loadData(x);
                    //cellEditing.startEditByPosition({row: rowIndex, column: 3});


                 // this.up('grid').getSelectionModel().setCurrentPosition({row:         rowIndex, column: 3});
                   cellEditing.startEdit(rowIndex,3);

                 }


        }
    }},
    { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
    { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
    { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone',editor:{xtype:'combo',store:unitStore,
     queryMode:'local',displayField: 'phone',
valueField: 'phone',selectOnFocus:true,triggerAction: 'all',
     } },

],
height: 200,
width: 400,
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
   });
```

Comment: There is a tutorial on formatting the questions on SO. Please refer it. It could help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am very new to SO. Will keep go through it before posting any further. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Ext.defer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-defer) to delay before calling startEdit function. Modified your sample in this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/9lm

Comment: I am using cell editing for a grid in Ext JS. I want to edit the cell by manually calling the startEdit method, rather than through clicks. How can I disable editor from being editable through clicks. I have a check column which will only allow editing of a particular column.

Comment: I modified beforeedit listener of celleditor plugin. and it worked.